# Verifying salted MD5 passwords in a Bcrypt form

Tags: php, hash, md5, bcrypt, php-password-hash

I am getting hashes and salts based on MD5 from a platform where users register.My platform is getting from a csv file the data of the new users(name,surname,username,password) and i have created a script in php that adds them automatically in my database.However i have a problem with the passwords because the platform i am using uses Bcrypt passwords.I have no idea how i can change the salted MD5 hashed passwords  to a Bcrypt password so that when the users that have registered to the other platform try to login in mine the authentication succeeds.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is weird. Why are you applying `md5` on `password_hash` .. You seem confused... Start with basic tutorials to fully understand the basics

Comment: What are you playing around with `password_hash()`/`password_verify()` ___and___ using `md5()` as well? You're reducing the entropy of the password, and hence its security..... just use `password_hash()`/`password_verify()`, and let it handle the salting and hashing for you... that's' what it does, and does well

Comment: i applied password_hash to an md5 so i can use password_verify as suggested to an other question but it did not work. That is why i am looking for something that does the same work password_verify does for Bcrypt passwords

Comment: password_hash()/password_verify() uses bcrypt by default

Comment: Unfortunatelly, t i get he passwords from an other app so they are encrypted as salted md5 and i cant change that.i just need to verify them with the clear text password.

Comment: If they're sending you MD5 then just use the `md5()` function to verify it. Just remember that [MD5 is not secure at all](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)